# Почему ноль без палочки?

Tags: фразеология

Когда хотят подчеркнуть чье-то ничтожество или никчемность, говорят, что он "ноль без палочки". А почему, собственно, без палочки? Где у нуля она должна быть и почему без нее плохо?))
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смысл выражения "ноль без палочки" заключается в следующем. Ноль "важничает", считая, что именно он  превращает незначительную единицу в число десять, но при этом забывает о том, что без палочки-единицы он будет просто пустым местом, не будет иметь никакого значения.

Изначальное значение фразеологизма, скорее всего, описывает ситуацию именно СРАВНЕНИЯ, например: Что такое Нью-Йорк без знаменитого Центрального парка? Да это просто ноль без палочки.Без активных людей администрация – ноль без палочки.

Answer (score 7):

По моему разумению, **палочка** — это единица, рядом с которой ноль превращается в десятку.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна, уточнение "без палочки" - излишне, это примерно то же, что "ты - ноль, а не десять".

Comment: дык получается, что не излишне, а очень даже симпатичный образ.

Comment: ноль - он и есть ноль. И так понятно, что никаких палочек там нет)

Comment: А "круглый ноль" не смущает? Или у Вас он бывает квадратным?

Answer (score -1):

По Айванхову ноль - материя, палочка - это единица=дух. Без духа материя пуста и бесплодна.
«Число 10, состоящее из 1 и 0, представляет собой дух и материю. Из Гиле (Hylc), то есть га хаоса, или из 0, рождается жизнь - 1. Вместе они дают 10, вот и элементы всех матемалмеских операций - десятка, десять пальцев. Единица представляет мужское начало, ноль - женское начало, оба вместе представляют материю, одухотворенную жизнью. И это образ того, как Бог создал мир: из нуля Он, благодаря действию единицы, сотворил все живое, и это есть десятка.»

Comment: Вы не могли бы давать ответы, более приличествующие ресурсу русского языка, но не нумерологии?