# Как говорят, когда чего-то очень мало?

Tags: фразеология

Есть такое выражение вообще? Только меня интересует "двухкомпонентное" выражение типа:

- вагон и маленькая тележка
- метр с кепкой

Как раз нужно противоположное первому. Вспоминал *кот наплакал,* но мне нужно именно *что-то и что-то* или *что-то с чем-то.* Конечно, если такое есть, оно ироничное, даже поболе, чем *вагон и маленькая тележка.*

Comment: капля в море. Ну не совсем то, может быть, но часто нужно сказать именно в этом смысле.

Comment: Артём! Порадовал вопрос, спасибо!  *Хрен да маленько, шиш да ни шиша* :))

Comment: ноль с палочкой из той же оперы

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, очень рад, спасибо! А также за ваши варианты — очень понравились! И user190920 тоже огромное спасибо! *Ноль с палочкой* слышал, но вот как раз и не получилось вспомнить, помогли. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С воробьиный скок, с воробьиный нос (короче воробьиного носа);
кошке на лизок;
на один зуб, на один укус;
по пальцам перечесть (пересчитать), по головам перечесть (пересчитать);
как (что) слону дробина;
с гулькин нос, с гулькин скок;
не ахти сколько, не бог весть сколько, не бог знает сколько, не так чтобы много, всего ничего;
с булавочную иголку, с булавочную головку, с булавочный укол;
размером с ноготь (с ноготок), не больше ногтя (при сравнении);
полтора человека;
раз-два и обчёлся, один-два и обчёлся, один-другой и обчёлся (один, другой — и обчёлся).
(Капля в море — уже названо.)
P. S. Про рост: метр с кепкой в прыжке, от горшка два вершка.
Ещё: маковая росинка, маковое зёрнышко.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!) Очень понравились предложения из комментариев, но рад увидеть знакомые "с гулькин нос", "раз два и обчёлся", "на один укус", "не ахти сколько".

Comment: "Полтора человека" не совсем подходит к моему контексту о количестве хлеба и другие тоже, но в любом случае возьму на вооружение для других ситуаций! "Метр с кепкой **в прыжке**" — прикольно.))

Comment: Спасибо за оценку ответа! Но (простите, Артём) — а **где** у нас контекст о количестве хлеба?

Comment: Эмм, Римма, вы знаете, я, конечно, об этом не говорил, отчасти и потому, что не хотел настолько сужать вопрос, поэтому слова о том, что не совсем подходит, вовсе не в упрёк сказал, в любом случае всё не помешает: что-то узнать, а что-то освежить в памяти. И обращаться к ответам в случае надобности.

Comment: Нормально вроде так о хлебе, да? *Ты знаешь, а хлеба-то у меня осталось вообще: 1) ноль с палочкой, 2) хрен да маленько, 3) шиш да ни шиша.* "С гулькин нос", "не ахти сколько", "всего ничего", "на один зуб/укус" тоже отлично вроде подходят, только поскольку они привычнее мне, кажется, что не так удивишь собеседника выражением.)))))))

Comment: О нолях и палочках — тут вопрос интересный. Ноль с палочкой — это **десять**. Ноль без палочки — это **ничто** (собственно ноль, ничего вообще). Вот тут: Ноль без палочки (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/128142). И вот тут: Почему ноль без палочки? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31843/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Comment: Я всегда думал, что ноль с палочкой - это ноль с палочкой внутри.

Comment: Если коротко (не углубляясь), то вот здесь: Что означает значок - перечёркнутый ноль? (http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3189022-chto-oznachaet-znachok-perecherknutyj-nol.html) Я ещё помню эти перфокарты. Тогда ЭВМ были ну очень большими.